# Interesting Question about Karma

Tags: bhagavad-gita, karma

I read and people say that for being a human before that we need to go for several lives of creature then we got this human life.

And as another thing that for karma people say if we did something bad to someone in this birth than for next birth he/she will be with you and punish you or help

So my question is :
If i did something good/bad with someone today, then that person and me will take several life as different creatures(After various different janm or life) so at that time how karma balance that ..

Example -  if i did something bad to x person
then i am going for several janam or life for be another human 
and that x person also gonna take several life for be another human for revenge

So how does karma balance this thing. for how much time/life x person is going to wait for the next life to get his revenge

Thank You

Comment: Those things what you said you heard may be true in some special cases, or may not be true. It's very difficult to talk about those things because we can talk just in general terms, and what you asked is quite specific, and may work in theory and in some specific cases.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in Bhagwata Gita, Karma is about doing your work irrespective of sorrow-happinness, appreciation/insult, etc.

Your punishment or other's punishment will be handled by almighty and will be delivered to you at appropriate time.

Bhagwata Gita states that how one person should be doing its work.

It doesn't explain on which janaam you will get the punishment.

I hope this helps !! Thankyou

Comment: Cite appropriate verses from Bhagavad-Gita.